# PHP is it possible to assign a variable to an "IF"

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I am starting on PHP, and i need a little help, I have my php file ytpost.php with the following content:
EDIT: I have my code a little bit disorganized,

```
<?php
$yturl = $_POST['urlyt']; //gets a youtube url
$yturlhttp = str_replace("https","http",$yturl); //replaces HTTPS with http
$ytid = substr(strstr($yturlhttp, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='), strlen('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=')); //removes everything before the video ID
$apikey = "blabla"; //youtube api
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$ytid&key=$apikey"); //using youtube api to get video info
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
$getvideoviews = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
$getvideolikes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'];
$getvideodislikes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount'];
$getvideofavorites = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['favoriteCount'];
$getvideocomments = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount'];
$paloma = "&#10004;"; //checkmark in spanish
$tacha = "&#10008;"; //cross in spanish
$minimumvideoviews = "4000"; //minimum video views to be accepted
$minimumvideolikes = "100"; //minimum video likes to be accepted

//echo "views: " . $getvideoviews . "<br/>"; //TESTING
//echo "likes: " . $getvideolikes . "<br/>"; //TESTING
//echo "dislikes: " . $getvideodislikes . "<br/>"; //TESTING
//echo "favorites: " . $getvideofavorites . "<br/>"; //TESTING
//echo "comments: " . $getvideocomments . "<br/>"; //TESTING
if ($getvideoviews < $minimumvideoviews) {
    echo "$tacha you dont have the minimum views to qualify for VIP ($minimumvideoviews minimum)<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "$paloma you do have the minimum views to qualify for VIP ($minimumvideoviews minimum)<br/>";
    };
 if ($getvideolikes < $minimumvideolikes) {
    echo "$tacha you dont have the minimum likes on your video to qualify for VIP ($minimumvideolikes minimum)<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "$paloma you do have the minimum likes on your video to qualify for VIP ($minimumvideolikes minimo)<br/>";
    };
?>
```

my problem is the following, i need to display something if both youtube views and youtube likes are exactly or over $minimumvideoviews and $minimumvideolikes, thank you.

, I dont have an idea on how to accomplish this,

Comment: Simple do: `$getvideoviews >= $minimumvideoviews AND $getvideolikes >= $minimumvideolikes`

Comment: Inside an if? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: Yes :) Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php , http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: I have been 8 hours searching for just that, my eyes hurt :), thank you so much @Rizier123